# Build a JSON structure by transposing database rows into column with pyodbc

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyodbc

I'm building the json which is expected as below:

```
{
    "diff": [            
        {
            "toys": 250,
            "kitchen": 100,
            "period": "201905",
            "totalamt": 2500  //sum of amount for toys+kitchen for that period
        },
        {
            "toys": 150,
            "kitchen": 50,
            "period": "201906",
            "totalamt": 1700
        }
    ]
}
```

Table structure and data in the backend db is as below (using which above json needs to be build):

```
id  period  category    amt     qty
1   201905  toys        500     250
1   201905  kitchen     2000    100
1   201905  garments    1000    10
1   201906  toys        200     150
1   201906  kitchen     1500    50
1   201904  toys        100     10
1   201904  kitchen     50      3
```

Note: id, startdate, enddate will be received as input  parameters.
I'm having challenge
1] when creating a dictionary (for each period) out of multiple db rows having different category (have applied filtered in db query to get only interested category)
2] get the totalamount for those category ( during that period)

My code :

```
import pyodbc
import json
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# id, startdate,enddate would be read through url query parameters(for mock build taking hardcoded values)
id = 1
startdate = '201905'
enddate =  '201906'
get_qty = "select period, category,qty from Table where id=? and (period between ? and ?) and category in ('toys','kitchen')"
cursor.execute(get_qty, id, startdate,enddate)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
complist = []
for row in cursor:
    complist.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

print(complist)
```

Comment: I tried using pandas for transposing row to columns but getting KeyError: 'period'  
```
data = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
p = df.pivot(index='period', columns='category', values='qy')
```  @GordThompson

Comment: @OluwafemiSule , checking if you have come across such scenario. Please provide inputs.